# How to fix material-ui `NaN` is an invalid value for the `width` css style property

Tags: material-ui

This warning comes out occasionally when rendering BottomNavigationAction. I also have problem with ListItem but fixed by disabling Ripple effect. Does anyone have idea about it?

```
Warning: `NaN` is an invalid value for the `width` css style property.
    in span (created by Ripple)
    in Ripple
    in TransitionGroup (created by ForwardRef(TouchRipple))
    in span (created by ForwardRef(TouchRipple))
    in ForwardRef(TouchRipple)
    in ForwardRef(TouchRipple) (created by WithStyles(memo))
    in WithStyles(memo) (created by ForwardRef(ButtonBase))
    in button (created by ForwardRef(ButtonBase))
    in ForwardRef(ButtonBase) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(ButtonBase)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(ButtonBase)) (created by ForwardRef(BottomNavigationAction))
    in ForwardRef(BottomNavigationAction) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(BottomNavigationAction)))
    ......
```

Comment: Tried setting a [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) instead of a [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) for the element's width property? ;-)

Comment: In this case, the component is in flex. so there is no fixed width for it.

Comment: Well, your error says it's `<span>` not happy with its `width` parameter value. I'd start there.